# Why does a shortcut to a secondary activity opens the main activity while in the background?

Tags: android, background, shortcut

My app has several activities, one of which has life in its own right, so I made a shortcut to it in the manifest via:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Now I have it in the `Widgets` zone. This secondary activity now opens when I click the shortcut that I put in my launcher, as I wanted.

However, there is something that does not work as I want: if the main app is working in the background (say, via the `home` button), clicking the secondary activity shortcut pop-ups the main app, not the secondary activity.

Why is that? Is this the natural behavior? Is there a way to open the secondary activity always, even side by side with the main app?

Thanks!

L.

Answer (score 1):

By surfing other stuff I found the solution of this.
Just add

```
 android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

in the secondary `<activity>` in the manifest. Here is the explanation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode